# Should I generate the exception message?

Tags: java, exception

Should I generate the exception message (in my example from the `link`parameter) or should my constructor take a `message` parameter?

```java
class ReadFromNotConnectedInputException extends RuntimeException {

    private String link;

    public ReadFromNotConnectedInputException(final String link)
    {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getLink()
    {
        return link
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return String.format("Cannot read from link \"%\", link not connected.", link);
    }
}
```

Comment: `inputName` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have opted for a `RuntimeException`, this would imply that you do not intend to handle it locally (close to where it was thrown), but at some higher level in the stack, where you handle many different exceptions.

In that context there will be no exception-specific logic involved; you'll write an error entry to the log file and clean up. Therefore a simple `message` property would fit the bill better than a separate String property + a complex `getMessage` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I would write it like the following. If I going to the effort of creating an Exception I would make it a checked Exception however.

```
class ReadFromNotConnectedInputException extends RuntimeException {
    private final String link;

    public ReadFromNotConnectedInputException(final String link) {
        super("Cannot read from link \"" + link + "\", link not connected.");
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link
    }
}
```

or

```
class ReadFailedLinkNotConnectedException extends Exception {
    public ReadFailedLinkNotConnectedException (final String link) {
        super(link);
    }
}
```

Comment: After reading http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html I chose an unchecked exception. Are you suggesting to never create my own unchecked exceptions?

Comment: Even though the source is C++, I decided to format the message on demand due to 4. in http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html

Comment: Either you expect to catch your specific exception in which case it should be a checked exception specific to what will happen when it is caught, or you don't expect it to be caught in which case it will end up in a log somewhere and the class you use doesn't matter too much. i.e. you can reuse an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept `message` parameter and call super constructor.

Answer (score 0):

IMO If the exception is part of **API** then you should take the message parameter in the constructor and pass it to the super.

Main advantage of that is that you can change the format of the message from different modules and if you keep a fixed format then all would be stuck with the same format.